# Correction function to correct endogeneity without instrumental variable

Tags: instrumental-variables, endogeneity

What happens if the disturbances are divided into residuals? This could be a solution to correct endogeneity without instrumental variable?

Comment: Can you clarify the first sentence? Disturbances and residuals are typically synonyms and it is not clear what it means for them to be to be divided. Do you mean what happens if you can isolate the problematic part of the residual that is correlated with the regressor of interest, by either eliminating it or controlling for it?

Comment: I mean i have this model:

$Y_i=1+x_i+\epsilon_i$

I know that $ x_i= w_i+\mu_i$

. But $w_i$  it is unknown. I was wondering what happen if .... $x_i=\frac{w_i+\mu_i}{\epsilon_i}$

Comment: This still does not make sense to me. Can you edit the question with this equation, and clarify what is observed, what is random, and any distributional assumptions.